# Delete from audit table in runtime

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-delete

We are using Oracle 12.1 database,

We want to create a table which will hold runtime audit data

The relevant/used data is only in a week time frame (older records will become irrelevant) and we'll delete older records using a job

Table holds 3 columns ID, Date (Primary key) and DAY_COUNT

We want to reset specific records, which can be achieve by updating DAY_COUNT to 0

But we want to keep the table small and the old data is irrelevant to us, so we consider using delete instead of update

Is it safe to reset records in runtime using delete ?

It seems the *not documented convention* to prevent using delete, but is it relevant in this case?

Comment: Oracle does not do full table locking by default so the runtime auditing (INSERTs) won't be affected by the DELETE.

Comment: my only caution: this audit table will likely get fragmented over time; delete does not reset the highwater mark of the table, so full scans will need to read in all blocks of the table (even if they don't have data), leading to poor performance if searches are not indexed.  This is easy to re-org online with "shrink space", but the rate of fragmentation will depend on throughput of data into and out of this table.